# Pull a new branch from upstream to your local system

Tags: git

There are two machines named Mine and Other who are working on the same codebase that is in bitbucket. I am working on the Mine machine, and another person, named Guy is working on the Other machine. Suppose Guy creates a new branch NB in Other and pushes it to the upstream by doing a git push --set-upstream origin NB. Now, I just want to bring that branch NB to my Mine machine as well. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure you get the changes do:

```
git fetch origin
```

And then to `checkout` that branch you can

```
git checkout NB
```